# WCF - Why no WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have hosted a couple of services in IIS with the following web.config. I can browse to the service but I get the message "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled."

Can anyone spot my mistake (I can't!)?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Calculator" behaviorConfiguration ="NotThrottled">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFTwoEndpoints/Calculate.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Calculator"
          contract="WCFTwoEndpoints.ICalculate" />
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="ThrottledCalculator" behaviorConfiguration ="Throttled">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFTwoEndpoints/ThrottledCalculate.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="ThrottledCalculator"
          contract="WCFTwoEndpoints.ICalculate" />
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NotThrottled">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="Throttled">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="19" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong - both services specify a service behavior which includes `<serviceMetadata>` and both services also have a MEX endpoint .... hmmm.... weird..... reboot IIS ??

Comment: The Service element has the name "Calculator" which should have been "WCFTwoEndpoints.Calculator" the name needs to be fully qualified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not fully qualified your service name with namespace. However this should manifest as an error when you try to run the service host.